# Quickblox sample chat Android privacy settings (block or unblock)

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

in quickblock sample chat, trying to add block and unblock for user **1-1** was unable to  include ALL of the desired items .Only one user was adding to list always this is my code

```
   privacyListsManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPrivacyListsManager();
    privacyListsManager.addPrivacyListListener(privacyListListener);
    privacyListsManager.setPrivacyListAsActive("public");

 QBPrivacyList list_all = null;
    try {
        list_all = privacyListsManager.getPrivacyList("public");
        Log.e("lists", "privacyCheck: " + list_all + list_all.getItems());


        privacyListsManager.setPrivacyList(list_all);

    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and on click of block, `private void blockUser() {`

```
   List<Integer> userIds = qbChatDialog.getOccupants();
    Log.e("userid ", "blockUser: " + id);

    QBPrivacyList list = new QBPrivacyList();
    list.setName("public");



    ArrayList<QBPrivacyListItem> items = new ArrayList<QBPrivacyListItem>();

    QBPrivacyListItem item1 = new QBPrivacyListItem();
    item1.setAllow(false);
    item1.setType(QBPrivacyListItem.Type.USER_ID);
    item1.setValueForType(String.valueOf(id));
    items.add(item1);
    list.setItems(items);
    try {

        privacyListsManager.setPrivacyList(list);
        privacyListsManager.setPrivacyListAsDefault("public");

    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  privacyListListener = new QBPrivacyListListener() {
        @Override
        public void setPrivacyList(String listName, List<QBPrivacyListItem> listItem){
            Log.e("block", "setPrivacyList: " );
        }

        @Override
        public void updatedPrivacyList(String listName) {
            Log.e("unblock", "setPrivacyList: " );
        }
    };

}
```

**The problem is `QBPrivacyList always used to be override with the block click values but I want the previous data to be saved.**